# Using a GenServer in Phoenix - the process is not alive

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server

I'm trying to get my head around working with a `GenServer` in Phoenix to accumulate information received from different clients to a web socket. The `GenServer` looks like this:

```
 defmodule HelloWeb.Stack do
    use GenServer

    @name {:global, __MODULE__} # this seems to help me to prevent having to drag the pid everywhere in the application

    # Client
    def start_link do
      #GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
    end

    def add(item) do
      GenServer.cast(@name, item)
    end

    def view do
      GenServer.call(@name, :view)
    end

    def remove(item) do
      GenServer.cast(@name, {:remove, item})
    end

    def wipe do
      GenServer.cast(@name, :wipe)
    end

    #Server
    def init(list) do
      {:ok, list}
    end

    def handle_cast(:wipe, _list) do
      updated_list = []
      {:noreply, updated_list}
    end

    def handle_cast({:remove, item}, list) do
      updated_list = Enum.reject(list, fn(i) -> i == item end)
      {:noreply, updated_list}
    end

    def handle_cast(item, list) do
      updated_list = [item|list]
      {:noreply, updated_list}
    end

    def handle_call(:view, _from, list) do
      {:reply, list, list}
    end
  end
```

This is the relevant part of my Phoenix channel:

```
def handle_in("answer", payload, socket) do
  HelloWeb.Stack.add(payload)
  {:noreply, socket}
end

def handle_in("answers", _payload, socket) do
  {:reply, {:ok, HelloWeb.Stack.view}, socket}
end
```

The weird thing is that `"answer"` seems to work every time I call it but `"answers"` always crashes the GenServer:

`[error] GenServer #PID<0.10032.0> terminating
** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call({:global, HelloWeb.Stack}, :view, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started`

I'm not sure how to share one GenServer between multiple channel actions. If I use `iex` all of the functions work exactly as I expect them to work, but in Phoenix the initialization and usage are spread.

I try to start the GenServer in Application as follows:

```
defmodule Hello.Application do
  use Application

  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
    children = [
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(HelloWeb.Endpoint, []),
      # Start your own worker by calling: Hello.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
      worker(HelloWeb.Stack, []),
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Hello.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
```

---

Sadly I have trouble debugging into the system and I can't figure out yet how to do that right. Lots of new things to absorb at once and I'm still a few a-ha's away from Elixir enlightenment. I have added two `debug` endpoints to debug things in very crude way:

```
def handle_in("debug2", _payload, socket) do
  {:reply, {:ok, %{ genserver: GenServer.whereis(HelloWeb.Stack) }}, socket}
end

def handle_in("debug1", _payload, socket) do
  {:ok, pid} = HelloWeb.Stack.start_link
  {:reply, {:ok, %{ genserver: GenServer.whereis(HelloWeb.Stack), pid: :erlang.pid_to_list(pid) }}, socket}
end
```

`debug2` just keeps returning `null` for `HelloWeb.Stack`, but when I run `debug1` the first time I get `null` and a valid `pid`, the second time it crashes with:

`** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:already_started, #PID<0.12310.0>}}`

This seems to indicate that it starts successfully, binds itself to a unique value and doing that for a second time is rejected because that particular process is already started. However I cannot use `HelloWeb.Stack` to reach it. Let me show the other relevant parts of the code after doing some changes and tests:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.Stack do
    use GenServer

    @name {:global,  __MODULE__}

    # Client
    def start_link do
      #GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: @name)
    end
```

This is how the worker is started in application.ex:

```
worker(HelloWeb.Stack, []), #how to verify it's really starting something and to what value it stores it's pid?
```

Comment: How/where are you starting the GenServer?

Comment: @Dogbert see updated answer

Comment: Can you try changing `name: __MODULE__` to `name: @name` in `start_link`?

Comment: Nothing changes. How would I know if the process really started and if so under what pid? The whole supervisor structure seems a bit "magic" because I can basically add anything in the children list but nothing ever generates an error.

Comment: I'd recommend browsing through the Applications and Processes tabs in Observer. Just run `:observer.start()` to start Observer.

Comment: I already tried Observer. Perhaps I should start the process I want to observe differently to be able to see it there? It seems like I only see stuff related to that particular instance of iex. Sorry to ask obvious things - pretty new to Elixir and Phoenix

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you aren't starting the GenServer with the application and therefore, the message is correct - e.g. there is no process alive.

The reason the `HelloWeb.Stack.add(payload)` function still works is because that's the intention of the cast functionality of GenServer's, e.g. you cast to the process because you don't care about the returned result at and whether it succeeds or fails (otherwise you would use `call`)

For example:

```
iex(1)> GenServer.cast(:non_existing_genserver, :add)
:ok
```

Here you can see that even though the GenServer doesn't exist, `cast` still returns an ack message, but in reality it's not going to go anywhere.

To solve your problem, navigate to your `application.ex` file and add in a worker to start the GenServer when the application starts up.

```
children = [
  #...other workers/supervisors
  {HelloWeb, []}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did have the worker start in application.ex although the syntax seems a bit different than yours. I've added it to my question.

Comment: Hmm make the name change like @dogbert suggested and then `GenServer.whereis(HelloWeb.Stack)` and see if the gen server is actually running

Comment: I changed my code and posted some more findings here.

Comment: can you change your @name to be `@name __MODULE__`

Answer (score 2):

#### `HelloWeb.Stack.start_link/1` is not defined and thus cannot be called

You implement the function `start_link/0`. It does not take any arguments. In the docs I usually see `start_link/1` being implemented in order to start your GenServer.

As I read the [GenServer docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-how-to-supervise), `HelloWeb.Stack.start_link/1` is always invoked when you start your GenServer as part of the supervision tree. In your case `HelloWeb.Stack.start_link/1` is not defined and thus cannot be called.

So I suggest you implement `start_link/1` like:

```
# Client
def start_link(_init_args) do
  #GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: HelloWeb.Stack)
end
```

What happens internally is something the Elixir/Erlang experts have to answer (Edits are very welcome!), but I think this is the root of your problem.